# Slots, modals and $emit actions - Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Quick question on slots and modals.

I have the following setup:

```
 <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showUnavailableModal = false">
    <p slot="body">[[ responseModalBodyText ]]</p>
    <button slot="footer" class="btn btn-gold text-uppercase" style="letter-spacing: 1px;" v-on:click="$emit('close')">[[ responseModalButtonText ]]</button>
 </modal>

  <script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
    <transition name="modal">
      <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div class="modal-container">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
              <slot name="body"></slot>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <slot name="footer"></slot>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </script>
```

So I'm attempting to change the button text given certain scenarios. However, there is an $emit method bound to this button, and this emit is not working...how do I get around this?

Comment: Do you want to close the modal when the button is clicked?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Hi Vamsi, yes :)

Comment: Everything present in paren is compiled in the parent scope itself. So  when the button is clicked it emits an event to its parent i.e the component inside which `modal` component is present

Comment: So you can just use `@click="showUnavailableModal = false"` on the button